# Plot RGB satellite image in Cassini-Soldner projection on a map in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, imshow, cartopy

I have a geo-referenced RGB satellite image from the MODIS instrument in geotiff format. **What is the correct way to plot it on a map using cartopy and preserve the RGB colours?**

The main obstacle I guess is the projection of the image which is Cassini-Soldner:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, osr

ds = gdal.Open('modis_201303261252_rgb.tif')

print(ds.GetGeoTransform())
(-1669791.8857914428, 250.0, 0.0, 1669792.327327792, 0.0, -250.0)

proj = ds.GetProjection()

inproj = osr.SpatialReference()
inproj.ImportFromWkt(proj)
print(inproj)

PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Cassini_Soldner"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",72],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-4],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

I tried to follow this example https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2015/03/02/geotiff/
and use cartopy to define a projection from an EPSG code. So I googled for Cassini-Soldner EPSG code (9806), but cartopy's `ccrs.epsg()` doesn't recognise it.

I want to use `plt.imshow()` method, but I'm a bit confused what to use as a projection keyword when the axis is created and what to pass as a `transform=` argument in `imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

(I would add this as a comment but I need 50 rep.)

Out of interest, how did you come by a Cassini projection MODIS RGB?

An alternative is to use a Cartopy pull request I've made, which allows for the time dimension to be used with GeoAxes.add_wmts(), so that you can pull MODIS RGB imagery tiles for your time from NASA GIBS straight into a Cartopy GeoAxes: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/788

Edit: this feature is in v0.15

Comment: I've got it from NEODAAS NERC Satellite Receiving Station, Dundee University, UK (http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk).

Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at your PR.